# possible race condition in pthread application (unable to detect)

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, valgrind, race-condition

Here is my problem with a pthread code. When I run the following commands:

```
 ./run 1
 ./run 2
 ./run 4
```

the first two commands (one thread and two threads) generate the same output. However with 4 threads (third command), I see different outputs.

Now when I run the following commands

```
 valgrind --tool=helgrind ./run 1
 valgrind --tool=helgrind ./run 2
 valgrind --tool=helgrind ./run 4
```

They generate the same outputs. The output values are correct though.

How can I investigate further?

The code looks like

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  // Barrier initialization
  if(pthread_barrier_init(&barr, NULL, threads)) {
    printf("Could not create a barrier\n");
    return -1;
  }
  int t;
  for(t = 0; t < threads; ++t) {
    printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
    if(pthread_create(&td[t], NULL, &foo, (void*)t)) {
      printf("Could not create thread %d\n", t);
      return -1;
    }
  }
  ...
}


void * foo(void *threadid)
{
  long tid = (long)threadid;
  for ( i = (tid*n/threads)+1; i <= (tid+1)*n/threads; i++ ) {
    printf( "Thread %d, i=%d\n", tid, i );
    for(largest = i, j = i+1; j <= n; j++) {
      if(abs( a[j][i] ) > abs( a[largest][i] ))
         largest = j;
    }
    for(k = i; k <= n+1; k++)
      SWAP_DOUBLE( a[largest][k], a[i][k]);
    for( j = i+1; j <= n; j++) {
      for( k = n+1; k >= i; k--)
         a[j][k] = a[j][k]-a[i][k]*a[j][i]/a[i][i];
    }
  }
  int rc = pthread_barrier_wait(&barr);
  if(rc != 0 && rc != PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD) {
    printf("Could not wait on barrier\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  printf("after barrier\n");
  ...
}
```

The main loop (which iterate over `i` in `foo()`) is divided by the number of threads. assume all variables are defined properly since as I said there is no problem with 1 and 2 threads.

Comment: It might help to try the StackOverflow debugger: just add the sections of code directly relevant to the issue to your question and other people will take a look at it.

Comment: When you say you see "different" outputs, do you see different outputs all of which are valid? If so, then there's nothing to investigate. If, however, you are seeing invalid output, then you need to investigate. Start by trying to reason out how that specific invalid output might get created. Add debugging statements if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what's going on, since you haven't given a complete compilable program to experiment with, but it's clear that each of the threads is reading/writing from sections of `a` that it aren't assigned to it, so you have race conditions all over the place. You are swapping sections of `a` so I'm not sure you can parallelize this algorithm as it stands.